# How to Interpolate Dates in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to mimic the EIA's methodology for interpolating data as shown here: [image: Snip of methodology]. Essentially, I want to calculate the last year value and 5 year average for each region, but those numbers are normalized to end on Friday; so for example, Friday 9/25/2020 was the most recent week released, but 9/25/2019 was not a Friday, so the EIA interpolates between the dates to derive a number for 9/25/2020.

What is the most effective way to do this in Power BI DAX? Would a measure or a calculated column be more appropriate if my data is structured as follows  [image: Snip of Table]?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for. Do you want to interpolate dates? or do you want to calculate averages?

Comment: I need to use the interpolated date to calculate the last year and the average values. Since the postings occur on every Friday, the day of the month the report is released changes each year, so the figure has to be interpolated to calculate the true average.